# 504 gateway time-out after 3 minutes (Apache in Docker)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, docker, http-status-code-504

I work on a Laravel project hosted in a Docker container with Apache. I have a script which call an API, it can take more than 3 minutes to respond, but I get this timeout error every time after 3 minutes:

504 gateway time-out

I tried to increase Apache `Timeout` to 600 (default 300) in `default.conf` file, and php timeout like `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` each to 600.

Anyone would know where could this 3 minutes timeout come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Either the API or the script that calls it

Comment: It's not the API because when I call it directly it has no timeout error even after 3 minutes. I also set php timeout in my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP + Laravel is sometimes a bit tricky.

- First check the cases that take less than 1 minute several times (for blocked request scenario).
- Then check "local"/"docker build" php config (for default timeout).
- Check Laravel's default timeout (sometimes the frameworks timeout is less than Apache's).
- Check what Yuriky suggests if you have proxies.

I don't know if this is your case, but if your file is very big, at some point PHP might be running out of memory, so if you still have the problem, also check PHP's memory limits.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the default php-fpm proxy timeout was set to 60 seconds in apache configuration.
Changing this value from 60 to a greater value as well as changing max_execution_time on PHP side solved the issue.

```
In file: /opt/docker/etc/httpd/conf.d/10-php.conf
   8: <Proxy fcgi://php-fpm:9000>
   9:   ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=60
    : </Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a script which call an API

Where is the API? On your infrastructure? Somewhere else? Where does the calling script run (on server/php, in browser/javascript, something else?)

> It's not the API because when I call it directly it has no timeout error even after 3 minutes.

Why didn't you already know that from how your code was behaving?

> 504 gateway time-out

Reported by what? Your infrastructure? The API?

> I tried to increase Apache Timeout to 600 (default 300)

You are aware that there are 60 seconds in a minute, therefore "300" is more than 3 minutes? You might not be aware that most browsers timeout at 5 minutes so using a higher value isn't going to help here.

> Anyone would know where could this 3 minutes timeout come from ?

Applying a LOT of guessing, it *may* be [default_socket_timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) (but that has a value of 60 seconds unless explicitly set) or [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) (30 seconds unless explicitly set).

But timeouts are there for a reason. If something is expected to take more than 30 seconds ro complete, you shouldn't be calling it synchronously from a page request in HTTP.